# NativeScript: Is there a hook for "on install" on device for own application?

Tags: android, ios, installation, nativescript, hook

I need to fetch some data on the installation of the application.
After googling for a while I couldn't find any resources on this. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply not possible, it's not a limitation by NativeScript but Android or iOS itself. You can not initiate anything unless user launches your application manually for the first time.

The only option could be fetching data on first launch of application.